# dompdf absolte positioned elemnts pagebreak

Tags: css-position, absolute, dompdf, page-break, absolutelayout

I have a dynamically generated page made up of some divs and tables and other elements inside those divs, all absolutely positioned. The lower divs can potentially have more contents in them, like comments/description, so they'll be longer then a page.

The problem is dompdf doesn't insert a page break, it just spans till end of first page and the rest of my html gets cut off...

Obviously page-break-before/after allways is not going to work since the content is dynamic, it may or may not span multiple pages depending on every entry.

Does anyone know of a simpler way to make it behave, apart from measuring content height, inserting page breaks with JS before html is generated and sent over to dompdf?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a large div containing all elements with in the body. Dompdf is not able to comprehend div to break into pieces. Once that was gone it arranged separate elements within the body tag just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that dompdf doesn't insert an auto page break in elements with `position:absolute`. Here's the bug report: [Auto page break in "position:absolute" elements not working](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1138)

So without knowing the details of your CSS, I would say that the problem is not about "breaking the div into pieces" but about treating `absolute` as literally *absolute* on this very page.